# Render data by typing in my search box

Tags: javascript, jquery

Code

```
var readAll = function () {
    $.ajax(
            {
                url: _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl +
                    "/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('PhoneBook')/items/" +
                    "?$select=Id, Title, pb_FirstName, pb_PhoneNumber" +
                    "&$orderby=Title,pb_FirstName, pb_PhoneNumber",
                type: "GET",
                headers: {
                    "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                },
                success: function (data) {

                    var _table = $('.table');

                    var data = data.d.results;

                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        _table.append("<thead>");
                        _table.append("<tr>");
                        _table.append("<td>" + data[i].Title + "</td>");
                        _table.append("<td>" + data[i].pb_FirstName + "</td>");
                        _table.append("<td>" + data[i].pb_PhoneNumber + "</td>");
                        _table.append('</tr>');
                        _table.append("</thead>");

                        _table.sort(function (a, b) {
                            return parseFloat(a.Title) - parseFloat(b.pb_FirstName)
                        });
                    }
                },
                error: function (err) {
                    alert(JSON.stringify(err));
                }
            }
        );
};


$(document).ready(function () {
    readAll();
});
```

I have a list that is shown in a HTML table. So now i build a HTML Search box. So when i click a name in the Search box, it should show me the name. How should I do that? And how can I sort the data by names?

Sorry for my misspelling

Comment: Please make an effort and show us what you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

I saved the var data above the var readAll. Then i put a span class under the name

Then i build this

```
$("#sort-button-lname").click(function () {
    console.log(data);
});
```

but I get undefined back